# Dynamic Page manipulation with Ember/jQuery/JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, ember.js

I am building an app using Ember.js with an OAuth system. I have this button for my users to login: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CY3Io.jpg

After my user logged in, it changes to this dropdown:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/3yWfl.jpg

The problem is, this currently only works after a page reload. Since I am building a single page, dynamic application, this is something I do not want.

This is the implementation I use:

```
{{#if isNotLoggedIn}}
        <li class="has-form" id="logInButton"><button onclick='FBLogin()'>Connect with Facebook</button></li>
{{else}}
        <li class='has-dropdown not-click'>
          <a href='#'><img class='profilePicture' {{bind-attr src=pictureLinkSquare}} height='25px' width='25px' /> Welcome, {{firstName}} {{lastName}}!</a>
            <ul class='dropdown'>
              <li>{{#link-to 'profile'}}Profile{{/link-to}}</li>
              <li><a href="#" onclick="FBLogout()">Sign Out</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
{{/if}}
```

So, how would I go about changing that button dynamically, what do I use for that? Can I implement this using ember (I was looking at the {{action}} helper?) or is it better to use something like jQuery to accomplish this task?

This is my first small, single page project, so I feel a bit lost.

Answer (score 0):

Creating a JSBin example would help understand your query better. 
However from what I understand, you would have not marked 'isNotLoggedIn' as a computed property that probably would be watching some property in your controller that controls the state of login.
Look at the example @http://emberjs.com/guides/object-model/computed-properties/
In example, pay special attention to how fullName computed property ended by putting a watch on base properties '.property('firstName', 'lastName')'. Usually when this is missed, the computed property does not get 'refreshed' immediately.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply! It was an interesting read and it seems to be a quite useful concept. However, my problem has changed a bit. I completely forgot to implement a jQuery .replaceWith(). So after the user logged in via Facebook, I replace the <li>-element with the login button with the <li>-element containing the picture, name and dropdown. The problem is that the Handlebar-helpers don't get replaced with the corresponding data when being placed via jQuery. I hope you get what I mean... This is how it looks: http://run.plnkr.co/XqQyHexSl1au6IKO/

Comment: Was unable to open the link, but Ember.js would be able to solve the issue for you here. Using {{actions}} would help as you mentioned.